# Minimum regular open set containing a given set in a T0 Alexandrov topological space

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory, modal-logic

What is known about the minimum regular open set containing a given set in a T$_0$ Alexandrov topological space?  I'm particularly interested in the condition for the minimum set happening to be first-order definable in the language of partial orders.  What are good sources to start with?

This question arose in a study of intuitionistic modal logic.

Comment: When you say Alexandrov topological space, do you mean the topology on a poset that consists of the upper sets?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes.

Comment: I think you mean to say minimal regular open sets rather than minimum regular open sets. The minimal regular open sets are the minimal elements in the separative quotient of your partially ordered set (if they exist of course).

Comment: @JosephVanName I mean minim**um** regular open sets, which exist only in very limited circumstances as you imply.

Comment: Ken Y. Thanks for clarifying. I should have read your question more carefully since you mentioned "the" minimum regular open instead of "a". However, this means that the only regular open set in $X$ is $X$ itself. In other words, the separative quotient of $X$ is must be a one element set. This is only possible if every two elements are comparable. i.e. if $X$ is a downwards directed set.

Comment: @JosephVanName I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.  Is it possible for you to clarify it?  What is the precondition for the situation you described?  Is that the existence of the minimum regular open set?  Please note that I've been asking about the minimum among the regular open sets _containing a given set_.

Comment: @JosephVanName I'd be also be the most grateful if you could point me to the proof of the minim_al_ regular open set being points in the separative quotient.

Comment: @JosephVanName After some work I found a finite poset that doesn't satisfy your description.  Could you state the precondition for what you said to work?

Comment: Ken Y. I see. You are talking about the minimum regular open set containing a set while I was thinking of simply the minimum non-empty regular open set. I apologize for causing confusion.

Comment: I should mention that $\overline{A},A^{\circ}$ are definable in $(X,A,\leq)$, so the least regular open set containing $A$, namely $(\overline{A})^{\circ}$ is definable in $(X,A,\leq)$, so if $A$ is a definable subset of $X$, then so is $(\overline{A})^{\circ}$. I am unsure if anything more substantial can be said about the definability of the minimum regular open set containing $A$ though with the way the question is asked so far.